# Flask request.get_data() not handling UTF-8 character

Tags: python, flask, curl

I have written a simple Flask web service in Python, that expects HTTP POST requests with a string as data.

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():

json_response = {}
data = request.get_data(as_text=True)

json_response['data'] = data
return json_response
```

When I try to call it with cURL using an ASCII string, it works fine:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hello -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "hello world"
{
  "data": "hello world"
}
```

But when I try to call it with a string that contains an UTF-8 character, the UTF-8 character is not read properly and is instead replaced by a replacement character (like the `decode('utf-8', 'replace')` would):

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hello -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "hello €"
{
  "data": "hello \ufffd"
}
```

I thought the whole point of `get_data(as_text=True)` was to read the data as a Unicode string? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure you're posting that `€` as UTF-8? Also, what if you declare `"Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"` in your cURL command? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, no. I'm not sure. I'm using Windows cmd, if that is of any interest. I tried adding "charset=UTF-8" but it made no difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this using Flask 1.1.2 on macOS using iTerm:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    data = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    return {'data': data}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
~ $ curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hello -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "hello world"
{
  "data": "hello world"
}
~ $ curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hello -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "hello world€"
{
  "data": "hello world\u20ac"
}
```

I'm led to believe your terminal isn't actually encoding that `€` as UTF-8 at all.

For further proof (and to avoid terminal problems) we can create a payload that is certifiably utf-8, and post it:

```
~ $ python3
>>> open("data.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8").write("kräftskiva")
10
~ $ curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hello -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d @data.txt
{
  "data": "kr\u00e4ftskiva"
}
~ $
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Windows cmd, and it does indeed seem that it didn't actually send the UTF-8 character as UTF-8. Doing as you suggest, using an UTF-8 encoded file as input instead, did the trick.